# predefined tag extraction to generate random value with php

Tags: php, regex, random, tags

i was looking for an easy way to generate random value with predefined tag
for example

```
[5,7,aAn]
```

i would like to extract this from text area, and replace it with random 
min would be 5  & max would be 7, and each time i can play with

```
"a" : lower case;
"A" : upper case;
"n" : numbers;
```

Is it possible to extract these value and use them with php to generate the predefined random.
Thank you

Comment: First, how are the data structured? json, string,or array then we can now what to do, you can also show us what you have done.

Comment: Just simple text but with predefined tag;
    if(isset($_POST['custom']) && $_POST['custom'] !== '') {
$custom=$_POST['custom'];  
 // need to check if contain the custom tag and replace it with appropriate value. 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what i understand from your question, you can try this:

```
$str = "5,7,aAn";
$strArray = explode(',",$str);
```

Assume that the length of your string will always be 3, the we can check for the highest and lowest values.
You need to loop the array and get the lowest and highest;

```
$max = 0;
$min = 0;
$str = '';



for($i=0;$i<count($strArray);$i++)
{
if(type($strArray[$i])=='string')
{
$str = $strArray[$i];
continue;

if($max < $strArray[$i])
{
$max = $strArray[$i];
}else{
$min = $strArray[$i];
}
}
```

//finally we must have gotten the $max and the min

```
$rand = mt_rand($min,$max);
```

//We can now split the new $str and ang get all the alphabets

```
$strArray2 = str_split($str);
```

Comment: Hi @Jerry Hanks, the answer is correct but we still need how extract the custom tag from the text area that contain not only the custom tag [5,7,aAN] but other text.

Comment: see what i think, you can check the data type of each element of the array, if it is a string, we can add it to another array of strings and if it is an integer, we can add it to another array of integer so that later we can this to handle it separately and search for the highest and the lowest values and use it as the max and min of the rand(), later you will handle the string separately.